# How to update popup selection text with JQueryMobile 1.4RC1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've previously used popups with JQueryMobile 1.3 and older without problem. With the new 1.4 RC1 I'm finding my popups don't update when I select a different item.

You can see an example here with JQueryMobile 1.3
http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/56hQ9/

And another here using JQueryMobile 1.4RC1 - identical code, but the select box no longer updates when different options are chosen;
http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/B9TqL/1/

Any ideas of what to try? the code is as follows;

```
<a href="#popupBasic16" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-position-to="origin" id="log_or_norm">Lognormal</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic16">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="radio" name="updown" id="updown46" value="Lognormal" checked="checked" />
            <label for="updown46">Lognormal</label>
            <input type="radio" name="updown" id="updown47" value="Normal" />
            <label for="updown47">Normal</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Javascript

```
$('select').selectmenu();

$('#updown46').click(function () {
    $('#log_or_norm .ui-btn-text').html('Lognormal');
    $('#popupBasic16-screen').click();
    document.select_choices.log_or_norm.value = "Lognormal";
    $('select').selectmenu('refresh');
});

$('#updown47').click(function () {
    $('#log_or_norm .ui-btn-text').html('Normal');
    $('#popupBasic16-screen').click();
    document.select_choices.log_or_norm.value = "Normal";
    $('select').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods

```
 $('#log_or_norm').text('Normal');
```

Another

```
$('#log_or_norm ').empty().append('Lognormal');
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/B9TqL/3/

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript has some errors as `document.select_choices` is not defined. If you want to update the value of your button use jQuery:

```
$('#log_or_norm').text("Lognormal");
```

It seems that in jQuery 1.4 they changed the HTML structure of the buttons, that's why your code `$('#log_or_norm .ui-btn-text').html('Lognormal');` doesn't work. Check the full page of changes [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/1.4-changelog).

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NwRBs/1/).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - I'd have given you the solution, but Sridhar got in first